# Duplicate package name in different project causes InvalidAccessException when run as plugin test

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin

Hi I am currently building an eclipse plugin project and I need to write tests to test some package private classes however the tests need to be placed in a different plugin project which has the actual application plugin in its dependencies.

In order to access the package private classes I named the test package the same as the actual one. The issue is that if I run it as a JUnit plugin test i get an InvalidAccessException

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class framework.resourcepack.datamodel.IResourceModel from class framework.resourcepack.datamodel.testCreateModel
at framework.resourcepack.datamodel.testCreateModel.testCreateLanguageModel(testCreateModel.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
at ...
```

This runs fine if i run as a standard junit. I have checked all dependencies and they are fine. Any help would be much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way around this is to make your test bundle a `Fragment` rather than a `Plugin` and set its host plugin as the one containing the classes you are testing.

This will mean the fragment uses the host plugin's ClassLoader and so should have access to those classes.